# SCHED_RR not returning the time slice to the correct thread

Tags: c, linux, real-time, preempt-rt

I am trying to study the behaviour of certain real-time scheduling policies in Linux. For that reason I have created 3 periodic threads, each one of them with a dummy workload. All of them have the same execution time ~5ms and their periods are 10ms, 20ms and 30 ms, respectively. Also their priorities are 95, 50 and 25, respectively.

I am trying to understand how SCHED_RR policy works but I am getting a strange behaviour:

1. A lower priority thread (thread #3) gets preempted while it is 20%
   into its timeslice.
2. A higher priority (thread #1) thread starts running.
3. Thread #1 finishes.
4. Thread #1 continues to run for another 80% of a timeslice, before
   resuming thread #3 execution (effectively "eating" the rest of thread #3
   timeslot).

The RR time slot is defined at 1ms at the moment. I am using kernelshark to visualize the task execution, so I know with quite some accuracy where it goes wrong.

[image: The part between the vertical lines is ~0.335 ms while the "tail" part indicated in red, is around 0.700ms, added together give us the timeslice duration.]

The code that makes the threads periodic:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &results[tid].thread_start_time); 
    
next = results[tid].thread_start_time;      // Init first next time to thread start time

    while (1)
    {
        // Define next arrival
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
        //trace_write("Current clock event: %ld.%ld", now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec);
        timespec_add_us(&next, period * 1000);
        //trace_write("Next clock event: %ld.%ld", next.tv_sec, next.tv_nsec);

        // Stop. Hammertime.

        trace_write("SUSPENDING!: Thread_%d", tid);
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME, &next, NULL);
        trace_write("WAKE: Thread_%d", tid);

        trace_write("RELEASE: Thread_%d", tid);

        // Perform workload
        workload(args->thread_number); // This produces a busy wait loop of ~5+/-100us milliseconds
        trace_write("FINISH: Thread_%d", tid);

    }
```

And the function for the dummy workload:

```
static void workload(int tid)
{
    struct timespec ct; // Current time
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &ct) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error Fetching Clock Start Time.");
        return;
    }
    struct timespec workTimer = ct; // Workload timer - default 5ms
    struct timespec slotTimer = ct; // RR Slot timer

    unsigned int counter = 1;

    while (1)
    {
        long micro_ct = getMicroTime(&ct);
        long micro_work = getMicroTime(&workTimer);
        long micro_slot = getMicroTime(&slotTimer);
        
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &ct) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error Fetching Clock Start Time.");
            return;
        }

        // Check the total workload time
        if (micro_ct - micro_work >= DEFAULT_BUSY_WAIT_TIME)
            break;

        // Check the RR timeslot. Sa
        if (inputpolicy == SCHED_RR && ((micro_ct - micro_slot) >= DEFAULT_RR_LOOP_TIME))
        {
            trace_write("RTS_Thread_%d RR Slot: %d", tid, counter++);
            slotTimer.tv_sec = ct.tv_sec;
            slotTimer.tv_nsec = ct.tv_nsec;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but if thread #1 "finishes" then what is it running the rest of the timeslice?

Comment: Exactly! I don't know! This part at the end continues after I have called the clock_nanosleep(). And the amount of time spent there is the exact amount of time that is left from the thread #3 timeslice.